# Location errors in Gridworld program?

Tags: location, gridworld

In my Gridworld program, I have a citizen that acts like a Bug, and a Criminal that turns the Citizen into a Victim. My Police actor, although not completely done, currently aids the victim. However, in a bounded grid, it does not recognize the next location is invalid. Here is my code.

```
public void act()
{
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    Location loca = getLocation();
    Location next = loca.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
    Actor neighbor = gr.get(next);

    if (gr.isValid(next))
    {
        ArrayList<Location> locs = getGrid().getOccupiedLocations();
        for(Location loc: locs) 
        {
            if (getGrid().get(loc) instanceof Victim)
            {
                Location prev = loc.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection()-180);
                moveTo(prev);
            }
            else if( neighbor instanceof Victim || neighbor instanceof Citizen)
                turn();
            else  
                moveTo(next);
        }
    }
    else
        turn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `Actor neighbor = gr.get(next);` after your if statement.

```
if (gr.isValid(next))
{
    Actor neighbor = gr.get(next);
    ArrayList<Location> locs = getGrid().getOccupiedLocations();

    for(Location loc: locs)
        ...
```

That way your `next` location is checked to make sure it's in the grid before trying to get an `Actor` from there.

One other thing, in your second if statement you call `getGrid().get(next)`, but you already have `gr` as the current grid, so you can just use `gr.get(next)`. There's no reason to create a variable and not use it.